# How to query different collections having a relationship?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Applied technologies: Python, MongoEngine, MongoDB.

Recently I started to create a program that the data was originally stored in a relational database.
All data came to me as CSV files, so I have imported these files using **mongoimport** command line tool. It worked fine and now I have documents like:

```
people_collection (people.csv file):

{
 id: MongoDB ID("84932809849329043"),
 person_id: 1
 name: Foo
}
addresses_collection (addresses.csv file):
{
 id: MongoDB ID("904389408904311"),
 addresses_id: 1,
 addresses_info: street 1 number 100, turkey,
 person_id: 1
}
{
 id: MongoDB ID("72910890434331"),
 addresses_id: 2,
 addresses_info: street 1999 number 595, japan,
 person_id: 1
}
```

I think I could accomplish this by issuing Manual Reference (described in the mongo docs reference) following this workflow:

1 - query all people I want:

```
people = [1, 2]
```

2 - query all addresses of the people with id 1, 2 I want:

```
people_addresses = {1: list_of_addresses_person_1, 2: list_of_addresses_person_2}
```

What is the good way to go?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is carrying a relational schema straight into MongoDB, which is usually not optimal.  With MongoDB, you have the ability to create more complex, nested documents, so you don't need to resort to classical, normalized tables.

In your example, you could embed the addresses directly into the people documents:

```
{
    people_id: 1,
    name: "Foo",
    addresses : [
      { 
         address_info : "....."
      },
      {
         address_info : "....."
      }
    ]
}
```

The advantage of this schema is that you don't need to perform a join between people and their addresses -- they always come in a single document.  Usually the schema should be selected according to your data access patterns, but in this particular case (where people tend to have few addresses and addresses are probably not shared between people), it is almost guaranteed that the above schema is a much better fit for MongoDB.

Comment: Ok, I understand it could be more reliable and correct (even smart), but like I said previously, all the was stored as CSV files and I need to handle all these collections in this way.